# Get buttons at the top right of JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

How can I get a reference to the buttons at the top right of an instance of a JInternalFrame such as the close button or the maximize button? I would like to call setName on them.

Comment: What do you plan to do after calling setName? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I am using a 3rd party tool that identifies components by name. By calling setName, I can use this tool to uniquely identify the components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/), which will allow you to return all the buttons used by the internal frame:

```
List<JButton> buttons = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JButton.class, frame);
```

or you could get the buttons individually by specifying the tooltip of the button you want to access:

```
JButton button = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JButton.class, frame, "ToolTipText", "Close");
```

Comment: +1 for using the toolTip as an identifier.  I don't have access to the SwingUtils you posted, so doing it by hand I got stuck with 3 references to a `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane$NoFocusButton`, not knowing which was which.

Comment: @splungebob, The `SwingUtils` class can be found at the link I provided. `doing it by hand I got stuck with 3 references` - if you have the references then you can just cast it to a JButton and invoke the `getToolTipText(...)` manually to get the text and then set the name based on the value of the tooltip.

Comment: I can get to the tips4java website, but the code is hosted on camick.com, which is blocked here at work.